# Confused on scoping and this

Tags: javascript, jquery

I received a code snipper from here: http://jsdude.wordpress.com/2012/12/19/jquery-event-callbacks-and-javascript-oop-methods/:

```
 var CounterButton = function(el){
    this.$el = $(el);
    this.counter = 0;
    this.bindEvents();
    this.myVal = 1;
}

CounterButton.prototype.bindEvents = function(){
    this.$el.click(this.clicked);
};

CounterButton.prototype.clicked = function(){
    this.increase();
    this.showMessage();
};
```

I am trying to figure out this specific line: `his.$el.click(this.clicked);`.  When you have `this` inside the `click` function does that refer to whats being clicked on which would be `this.$el`?

Comment: `$(this)` and `this` are very different

Comment: Please read the entire article and you will see that he explains which is the correct approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> does that refer to whats being clicked on which would be this.$el?

No. it is refering to a function named `clicked`  which inside the object which holds the `bindEvents` method

However `this` in the event handler referes to the **DOM ELEMENT** !
consider this simple code :

```
$("body").click(this.do1);

function do1()
{
 alert(this.tagName); //BODY     
}
```

please notice that

```
$el.click(this.clicked)
```

is like :

```
var that=this;
$el.on('click',function {}(that.clicked()));
```

Answer (score 0):

`this.$el` refers to: `$(el)`; `(var CounterButton = function(el){...)`

`this.clicked` refers to: `CounterButton.prototype.clicked = function(){...`

In jQuery, `$(el).click` is a function that can either trigger or listen for a click. If passed a function, it will listen for a click in the element 'el', and execute that function when one is performed.

Inside of the function 'this.clicked' though, something confusing happens.. jQuery passes the element that was clicked to the function 'this.clicked', so 'this' is 'el' from the constructor.

```
CounterButton.prototype.clicked = function(){
    this.increase(); // this refers to the element 'el'
    this.showMessage(); // this refers to the element 'el'
};
```

Which is why he gets this error:
http://jsdude.wordpress.com/2012/12/19/jquery-event-callbacks-and-javascript-oop-methods/console/

You can fix that by doing closure:

```
CounterButton.prototype.clicked = function(){
    var self = this;
    return function () {
        self.increase(); // self refers to CounterButton
        self.showMessage(); // self refers to CounterButton
};
```

And instead of passing this.clicked, pass this.clicked()

```
 this.$el.click(this.clicked());
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer the original question about `this` inside of a jQuery event handler: No, it is not necessarily the element that was clicked. Specifically, per http://api.jquery.com/on/:

> When jQuery calls a handler, the `this` keyword is a reference to the
>   element where the event is being delivered; for directly bound events
>   this is the element where the event was attached and for delegated
>   events this is an element matching `selector`. (Note that `this` may not
>   be equal to [`event.target`](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/) if the event has bubbled from a descendant
>   element.) To create a jQuery object from the element so that it can be
>   used with jQuery methods, use `$(this)`.

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery this always refers to the DOM element on which the event handle was bound (http://api.jquery.com/bind/).

For a better understanding of this in general you can take a look here: [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/javascript-this-keyword)

If you read the whole post you will see why this example is wrong (the following text is from the article you linked to):

The clicked() method was called with wrong context. If you never heard about function call context in javascript, you should read this great article. By default, the context object for event callback in jQuery is the target HTML element. But that’s easy to fix, we just need to slightly modify the bindEvents() method:

```
CounterButton.prototype.bindEvents = function(){
    this.$el.click($.proxy(this.clicked, this));
};
```

$.proxy is jQuery’s version of function (or scope) binding. This method returns new function, which will always be called with context object, provided as second argument. You can read more in the official jQuery documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Some people are mixing up things. `this` from your example has nothing to do with behavior of `this` inside of jQuery functions.

Usage of code example is following:

```
var myButton = new CounterButton(domElement);
```

Every this, since it's constructor will be: `this == myButton`